# Do all real numbers have a simple infinite continued fraction representation over the integer square roots?

Tags: reference-request, radicals, continued-fractions

I use $\mathbb{N}^0$ to denote the non-negative integers. Let $r$ be a real number. Clearly, for some $r$, the equation
$$r=\sqrt n + \frac1r$$
does not have a solution $n \in \mathbb{N^0}$ (more specifically, $r-\frac1r$ must be a square root of some non-negative integer for the above to be true. In the case of $r=0$, we exclude $\frac1r$.) I am wondering the following:

> Does every $r \in \mathbb{R^+}$ satisfy:
>   $$r=u_0 + \frac{1}{u_1+\frac{1}{u_2+\frac{1}{\ddots}}}$$
>   For not necessarily distinct integer square roots $u_0,u_1, u_2 \dots$, with $u_0 \geq0$ and $u_1,u_2\dots >0$? The above fraction is infinite.

To me, this problem smells like Khinchin or Ramanujan, although I cannot find anything addressing this question specifically, and I certainly cannot approach it like my first example. I would like either a reference that discusses this question or help in answering it.

I say the answer to my question is 'no,' but my only justification is my intuition saying that the bound between $\mathbb{R^+}$ and $\mathbb{N^0}$ should take more than some square roots and fractions to leap. But if the answer is no, then what conditions must $r$ satisfy for it to be true?

> **My attempt:** if $r$ is to satisfy my equation, then (I think?) it must follow that:
>   $$r(u_1u_2u_3\dots) = u_0u_1u_2u_3\dots+1 \implies r=u_0+\frac{1}{u_1u_2\dots}$$
>   So, in order for $r$ to have such a representation, the RHS must be true. In other words, if $r$ is to have such a representation, it must be expressible as the sum of a non-negative integer square root and the reciprocal of the square root of some positive integer. I believe this encompasses all integers? Actually yes, I am almost certain this is the case. Leaving this here and going to work on it more in the meantime.

Comment: The real interesting question is what subset of real numbers have a simple continued fraction with a predictable sequence of precomputable terms.  The transcendental e, Euler's number, has a simple pattern. Pi does not. Interestingly, pi does have a predictable generalized continued fraction. My interest is in predicting which reals fall into which category. Do some real numbers not even have a predictable general continued fraction? I find it interesting that we dont define subsets around these criteria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All positive integers are integer square roots. And every positive real number has a continued fraction expression over the positive integers. So the answer to your question is yes.